# php-fpm and nginx security isolation not working....or may be my understanding is not correct

Tags: permissions, php, nginx, fpm

I followed the following tutorial to do isolation of my two websites.
`https://www.vultr.com/docs/use-php-fpm-pools-to-secure-multiple-web-sites/`

Here is what I did:

1. Created two users and then assigned them permissions.

   ```
   $ sudo useradd site1  
   $ sudo useradd site2  
   $ usermod -a -G site1 www-data  
   $ usermod -a -G site2 www-data
   ```
2. Assigned directory permissions

   ```
   $ sudo mkdir /var/www/site1  
   $ sudo chown -R site1:site1 /var/www/site1  
   $ sudo mkdir /var/www/site2  
   $ sudo chown -R site2:site2 /var/www/site2  
   $ sudo chmod 770 /var/www/site2
   ```
3. Created two fpm pools

   ```
   $ sudo cp /etc/php/7.4/fpm/pool.d/www.conf /etc/php/7.4/fpm/pool.d/fpm-site1.conf  
   $ sudo cp /etc/php/7.4/fpm/pool.d/www.conf /etc/php/7.4/fpm/pool.d/fpm-site2.conf
   ```
4. Then configured those pools

   - Changed the top line inside the brackets that sets the pool name from [www] to [site1].
   - Changed the line user = www-data to user = site1.
   - Changed the line group = www-data to group = site1.
   - Changed the line listen = /var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock to listen = /var/run/php/php7.4- site1-fpm.sock

   Did the same for second pool.
5. Configured nginx and defined those pools in each site

   ```
   location ~ \.php$ {  
       fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm-site1.sock;  
       include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;  
   }
   ```

   Did the same for site2 and then restarted php-fpm and nginx.

Now coming to the problem. All PHP pages of first site are owned by `site1:site1` while second site are owned by `site2:site2`. Except one page of second site which is owned by `site1:site1`.
I was expecting that when I will try to access that page of second site in browser then I will get some error (because it is not owned by `site2:site2`) but I didn't receive any error and page opened normally.
Do you think it is working correctly and my understanding as to how it should work is incorrect? Or that page in second site shouldn't have opened in browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've only changed permissions on the `/var/www/site2` directory itself, but not on the files inside – they are presumably still world-readable (with 0644 permissions). If the file is readable by 'other', then ownership doesn't really matter as the `site2` user account still has permissions to read the file.

Comment: You are right. I changed permission to 640 and now it is working fine.